# How to modify R data frame so that coordinates are readable by ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, mapping, ggmap

I am working with a data set that maps crime locations. Unfortunately the crime data's location is stored in a single column as text in the format (x.xxxxxx, y.yyyyyyyy). The number of decimal places varies between the data points. This data set contains hundreds of data points. How can I modify this particular column such that the x and y coordinates are separated and stored in two separate columns in the data frame?

Thank you for the help

Comment: A small [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help greatly. You can probably get away with 5 to 8 example rows from your data, and be sure to include your desired output. Also include any steps you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with fake data:

```
# Fake data
d = data.frame(x=c("(8.4344, 93.593)", "(6.44, 91.3)"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(tidyverse)

d %>% 
  # Remove parentheses
  mutate(x = gsub("\\(|\\)", "", x)) %>% 
  # Separate into two columns
  separate(x, into=c("lat","lon"), sep=", ") %>% 
  # Convert to numeric
  mutate(across(lat:lon, as.numeric))
```

> ```
>      lat    lon
> 1 8.4344 93.593
> 2 6.4400 91.300
> ```

Or, using regular expressions to extract latitude and longitude:

```
d %>% 
  mutate(lat = str_extract(x, "(?<=\\()[0-9-\\.]*"),
         lon = str_extract(x, "(?<=, )[0-9-\\.]*"),
         across(lat:lon, as.numeric))
```